# Django Admin search query not hitting Postgres index

Tags: django, postgresql, django-admin

I'm doing a full-text search with a GIN index in Postgres (all localhost), and when I write my own query and run it in psql, I am getting great response times and `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` reports an index hit (woohoo), however when querying via the Django Admin search box with the **same search terms**, the index is not scanned and the query takes upwards of forever to complete.

My index is created thusly via the [fully-awesome pg_trgm Postgres extension](http://www.depesz.com/2011/02/19/waiting-for-9-1-faster-likeilike/):

```
CREATE INDEX name_gin ON entity USING gin (name gin_trgm_ops);
```

This query hits the index and takes a blazing **84ms** to search through 900k full-text records:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM entity 
WHERE name LIKE UPPER('%dubteeeff%') 
 AND name LIKE UPPER('%django%');
```

The exact same query, as created by the Django Admin interface, takes **938ms**:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM entity 
WHERE UPPER("entity"."name"::text) LIKE UPPER('%dubteeeff%') 
  and UPPER("entity"."name"::text) LIKE UPPER('%django%');`
```

The only difference appears to be the way the columns are referenced--I'm fairly new with Django and Postgres--is there some Postgres config setting or Django admin QuerySet-something, or a RawQuery that I could override or modify to speed this up?  I don't want my Admin page to at best be slow and at worst, drag the rest of the site down with it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The difference is that in your query the column is referenced. In the djange Query an expression `upper(name)` is used, which is not indexed. Araqnid is right that you probably need an index on `upper(name)` rather than "just" `name`. Or teach django to not apply the `upper` function (maybe tell it to *not* make the query case-insensitive)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look like you need to add an index on `entity(upper(name))` rather than `entity(name)` for the case-insensitive search that Django is generating.

Comment: Thanks--I can't believe I didn't notice that.  Generated the uppercase index and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Is this perhaps an issue with COUNT(*) being slow in Postgres?  You might want to check into modifying your queries to return estimates instead of exact counts, as that is a known issue with Postgres.

Comment: Thanks but I've already done that-- the COUNT(*) by itself is quite fast.  Plus, if that were the issue, why would the query ever be fast?

Comment: Ah--yes.  Looks like the issue has to do with Postgres not interpreting `UPPER("entity"."name"::text)` the same way as `name`.  Not sure why that would be, or how to stop Django from doing that.  Good luck!

Comment: Django will use `UPPER()` in the SQL if you filter case insensitive by using the `i*` keywords: `.filter(name__istartswith=...)`, or `icontains`