# Add db_index to Django User model?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-queryset

I have a custom user model that takes in the following fields:

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=120, unique=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

I know `username` and `email` automatically adds a `db_index` because it is set to `unique=True`.

Does it make sense to add `db_index=True` for my `full_name` and `is_active` fields?

I have a search feature that checks if the regex matches the `full_name`. In my model managers, I also filter against `is_active=True`.

I would like to optimize querys, but don't want to add tables to my database if it isn't necessary.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,just add `db_index=True` into your field like this

`full_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True,db_index=True)`

After you migrate it, your database will create a index for this filed.

Refer this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#db-index

> **Field.db_index**
>
> If True, a database index will be created for this field.

Answer (score 0):

Whether the index is used for `full_name` if you search using a `regex` is doubtable. You want to make sure of that by looking at the output of the query planner (e.g. postgres: `EXPLAIN ANALYZE select * from myuser where user=...;`).

If it is not used (for example because the regex lower cases everything) then you have to create a different index. For example on the lower cased value or even a GIN index (for partial matches).

- [Django Admin search query not hitting Postgres index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284546/django-admin-search-query-not-hitting-postgres-index)
- http://blog.it-agenten.com/2015/04/tuning-django-orm-text-queries/